# Which Ethereum library is the one to use nowadays? Contract events on mobile must work

Tags: web3js, events, drizzle, ethers.js, mobile-wallet

I used `drizzle` in our dApp and contract events work fine on Desktop browsers with MetaMask. However, on mobile (tested with Rinkeby deployment on MetaMask and Status on Android) the contract events don't get through. I made a minimal setup to test different libraries: [dev-dApp](https://github.com/benjaminaaron/dev-dApp).

Turns out I receive contract events on mobile *only* when using `ethers.js`, not via `drizzle`, `web3.js` and `@truffle/contract`. Is this actually the case or do I have errors in my setup? Is `ether.js` nowadays the way to go? Then I would go ahead and rewrite my dApp.

Comment: web3.js v1 or higher.

Comment: Could you point me to a dApp that uses web3.js and where contract events work on mobile? Then I can check out how they do it.